# how to select nodes with different tags using DOM?

Tags: java, xml, dom, domparser

i have an xml file that looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
 <HWData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NE MOID="WBTS-42" NEType="WBTS">
   <EQHO MOID="EQHO-1-0" >
     <UNIT MOID="UNIT-FAN-1" State="enabled"></UNIT>
     <UNIT MOID="UNIT-FAN-3" State="enabled"></UNIT>
   </EQHO>
  </NE>
  <NE MOID="RNC-40" NEType="RNC">
   <EQHO MOID="EQHO-3-0" >
     <UNIT MOID="UNIT-FAN-5" State="disabled"></UNIT>
     <UNIT MOID="UNIT-FAN-6" State="disabled"></UNIT>
   </EQHO>
  </NE>
</HWData>
```

i am asking for how can i get NodeList containing "NE" and "UNIT" tags using DOM ?
thanks

Comment: Are you asking for a `NodeList` with **6** values? I mean, the 6 elements with the following MOID's: `WBTS-42`, `UNIT-FAN-1`, `UNIT-FAN-3`, `RNC-40`, `UNIT-FAN-5`, `UNIT-FAN-6`

Comment: There's no built-in method for that in DOM. You can get two NodeLists, one for `NE` elements and one for `UNIT` elements. You could use XPath though. See this [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) for more detail.

Comment: okay @Andreas i thought that there is a way to do that using DOM ,i'll try with XPath now thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
public static List<String> MOIDList(File file) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException, XPathExpressionException{
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder(); 
    Document doc = db.parse(file);

       XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
       XPathExpression exp = xPath.compile("//NE | //UNIT");
       NodeList nl = (NodeList)exp.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        List<String> MoidList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        String moid=((Element)nl.item(i)).getAttribute("MOID");
            MoidList.add(moid);
    }
    return MoidList;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it manually:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class XmlDomTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("/path/to/your/file");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder(); 
        Document doc = db.parse(file);
        Set<String> filteredNames = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("NE", "UNIT"));
        NodeList list = collectNodes(doc, filteredNames);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++)
            System.out.println(list.item(i).getNodeName());
    }

    private static NodeList collectNodes(Document doc, Set<String> filteredNames) {
        Node ret = doc.createElement("NodeList");
        collectNodes(doc, filteredNames, ret);
        return ret.getChildNodes();
    }

    private static void collectNodes(Node node, Set<String> filteredNames, Node ret) {
        NodeList chn = node.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < chn.getLength(); i++) {
            Node child = chn.item(i);
            if (filteredNames.contains(child.getNodeName()))
                ret.appendChild(child);
            collectNodes(child, filteredNames, ret);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The xpath to only select the `MOIDS` is `//NE/@MOID | //UNIT/@MOID`.

You should have a look at my open sourced Xml-parser-library [unXml](https://github.com/tajakobsen/unxml). It's available on [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22unxml%22).

*You can then do the following:*

```
import com.nerdforge.unxml.Parsing;
import com.nerdforge.unxml.factory.ParsingFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import java.util.List;

public class Parser {
    public List<String> parseXml(String xml){
        Parsing parsing = ParsingFactory.getInstance().create();
        Document document = parsing.xml().document(xml);

        List<String> result = parsing
            .arr("//NE/@MOID | //UNIT/@MOID", parsing.text())
            .as(String.class)
            .apply(document);
        return result;
    }
}
```

*`parseXml` will return the result:*

```
[WBTS-42, UNIT-FAN-1, UNIT-FAN-3, RNC-40, UNIT-FAN-5, UNIT-FAN-6]
```

You can also create more complex nested datastructures if you need. Give me a comment here, if you want an example on how to do it.